# Installing GNOME UBUNTU on ASUS Transformer T100TAM

Tags: ubuntu, grub2

So far I've (almost) successfully installed ubuntu except grub failed to install (as expected by [this tutorial](http://www.jfwhome.com/2016/01/04/latest-steps-to-install-ubuntu-on-the-asus-t100ta/) and now I need to install the bootloader. I've booted from the USB stick, hitted 'c' and tried:

```
linux (hd2,gpt5)/boot/vmlinuz-3.13-xxxx root=/dev/mmcblk0p5
initrd (hd2,gpt5)/boot/initrd-3.13-xxxx
```

without success. I've found in the comments that one had the same problem that he fixed with:

```
linux (hd2,gpt5)/boot/vm root=/dev/mmcblk0p2
initrd (hd2,gpt5)/boot/ini
boot
```

but that didn't work for me.

> error: file 'boot/vmlinuz' not found
>
> error: file 'vm' not found

Do you have any idea on solving this one?

Comment: You should check the exact file names for the kernel image and initrd in `/boot`. Also, make sure that the root partition is named correctly. You seem to be following the instructions quite literally. Instead try and understand what they are and adjust the commands accordingly for your system.

Comment: You need to discover which device contains your boot partition and what isthe exact name of the kernel that is located therein is named.  A good starting point is to use the lsblk utility to find the boot partition.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is more up to date guid. 
[Try it out](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VTzciobFlp7nO2A_M7RNoqYajN8c9AgR/view)

But it was useful for me even with newest guide so:

You did everything right but forget about this(from the [yours](http://www.jfwhome.com/2016/01/04/latest-steps-to-install-ubuntu-on-the-asus-t100ta/) guide):

> Fortunately, grub has good auto-completion features, so you can hit twice as you type, and grub will list possible completions for you — just keep trying until you see the various vmlinuz kernels.

Hit twice =

> Tab button

For you `vmlinuz` is located in another disk or may be you just copied and pasted whole command in prompt, it is a mistake. You should find where is your `/boot` located by changing this `linux (hd#,gpt#)` part of the command properly for your machine. Then when you will find on which disk your `/boot` part located you should write correct version of the kernel by hitting tab on this stage:

```
linux (hd#,gpt#)/boot/vmlinuz-
```

`grub` will list possible completions for you during all way.
Also don't forget about this:

> The `root=/dev/mmcblk0p5` will also depend on the partition you installed to. It will be your root partition.[...] Only the number after the ‘p’ will change — and it will probably be p5, p6 or p7.

In my case it was p2.

Good luck! And remember:

> Don’t be disheartened — keep trying.